# How to diable escape key when wpf application is on Topmost

Tags: wpf, topmost

how to disable the escape key when wpf application is on topmost? When my application is topmost and some other app is on Presentation or full screen by clicking on escape is closing other app in presentation mode. How to block this behavior. I don't want to stop other app from being Full screen.

Comment: Is your question how to prevent other apps from handling key presses while your app is running?

Comment: Correct, when my app is topmost I don't want other apps which is in presentation mode to close when esc is clicked